Dostoyevsky's shift from witness to omniscient narrator in *The Devils*
I find it quite surprising from the structural point of view of the novel that in the first part and up to some few sections of the second part of The Devils Dostoyevsky's narrator is fully a witness narrator, while all of a sudden he changes to omniscient narrator, roughly about half of the book. Why?
By the former I mean, the narrator describes the events making it clear that he was there and what he tells is what his memory can recover, or in those where he was not present he managed to know from other people's mouths what happened and what was said, he even emphasizes several times that he is not sure that what he was told is true or that he remembers all exactly - that's particularly noticeable in the after Church meeting at Mrs. Stavrogin's house, which is the chief event of the first part, and where in my opinion the narrator even works hard to make convincing the fact that he was invited to such a meeting.
By omniscient narrator I mean its conventional meaning. We notice that he describes even thoughts of Mr. Stavrogin walking alone after the secret exit at late night from his mother's house to go to find some other characters, shortly after the beginning of the second part.
